# How to detect that a window is currently running a modal dialog?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, modal-dialog

I have a wizard interface (so a property sheet with property pages).

On one of the pages, I am running a background timer to keep detecting whether a given external thing is true or not (well, I compile a list of attached visible USB security dongles).

But when this page shows a modal dialog box - e.g. a MessageBox, I want to suspend/ignore the timer notifications.

I can do that by simply killing the timer - running the message box - then starting the timer anew. That works perfectly but requires that all calls to MessageBox remember to do this.  Not a huge deal, but inelegant.

Now, I could also wrapper MessageBox so that I use a helper wrapper function which does the suspend / resume timer for the caller.  That's a valid thought - but it still requires maintenance coders to always remember to call my wrapper function, and this doesn't work well for other modal dialog boxes that might need to be run which also would need to have the suspend/resume timer dance performed.

What I believe is ideal is to leave the timer running, but have the timer handler itself check if we're currently running a modal dialog, and if so, simply ignore the timer notification (the timer will continue to spew notifications in a few moments - and eventually we'll be done with the modal dialog [message box] and we can go ahead and handle the timer notification then).

But what I do not see is a mechanism by which to ask "Am I running a modal dialog right now?"

From the POV of the page's timer handler - it doesn't know if a modal dialog box is in progress or not.  `IsWindowEnabled()` returns true - so at least the standard windows `MessageBox()` does NOT disable the parent window... which leaves me mildly confused as to how it is locking out button clicks on its parent window (my mind is a sieve these days - maybe the answer is obvious and I'm just getting old ;) )

Anyway - what am I missing?  What is a simple test for ***"Is a modal dialog box running right now in this thread / as a child of this window?"***

Thanks for any gentle clues you might have to offer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was asking `IsWindowEnabled()` from the context of the property page - which is a child window within the wizard dialog.

Changing that to `GetParent()->IsWindowEnabled()` does return `false` while running a modal dialog.

Comment: A modal dialog disables its owner until it is closed. That's not the only reason for a window to get disabled. Any code can call [EnableWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enablewindow). While that may solve your immediate issue, it is certainly not a general solution. It will report false positives.